# ChromeDriver has started to create blank screenshots?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using ChromeDriver to create automated browser tests. This stopped working today, taking a look at the screenshots that are saved in the database, they are all blank pixels.

Why?

## Version

ChromeDriver 2.29.0

## Screenshot

[image: Empty screenshot]

## Hexdump

[image: Start of hexdump]

[image: End of hexdump]

## Code (c#)

```
foreach (var testStep in testSteps.ToList())
{
    var testStepRun = new TestStepRun();
    repo.createTestStepRun(testStepRun);

    /* I omit this function in my posting but will include it if needed */
    RunTestStep(testStep);

    try
    {
        testStepRun.ScreenshotPNG = driver.GetScreenshot().AsByteArray;
    }
    catch(UnhandledAlertException)
    {
    }

    repo.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Which browser you are using ? Did you checked on different browser or downgrading the browser version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's related to your Chrome browser.
Downgrade to version 58: https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

Comment: Not yet, I've had the same issue and after downgrading Chrome to version 58 my problem was solved...

Answer (score 0):

It can be related to current ChromeDriver version and Chrome version we use. I`m facing the same issue. I have tried some variants of ChromeDriver/Chrome version to find working one. You can also have a look at the existing issue:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3700