# How to get screenshots from headless ChromeDriver with Selenium in Java/Linux?

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser

I have this Java app that on Ubuntu, with Selenium and ChromeDriver, scraps some websites and retrieves some data. I wanted to automate error logging, including a screenshot being created if certain exceptions are thrown(all already implemented and working). Basically this is where I instantiate my driver:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.home") + driversPath + "chromedriver");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
if(headless)
    options.addArguments("--headless");
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, true);
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.TAKES_SCREENSHOT, true);
this.driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
this.driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1366, 768));
```

And this is how I create screenshots from it:

```
File srcFile = ((TakesScreenshot) this.driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    try {
        // creates file at System.getProperty("user.dir")
        FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, new File(path));
    //catch and so on
```

With `Boolean headless = false;` this works exactly as I wanted, and I can see my screenshots just fine. Now I would like to test in some VPS and needed to use it headless first locally.

With `Boolean headless = true;` I noticed my automation worked as supposed by the log that was generated but when I intentionally got offline to throw some errors, I noticed all screenshots were blank images. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879525/chromedriver-has-started-to-create-blank-screenshots) but since with headless turned off I got screenshots, this answer doesn't matter to me.

I tried using `setHeadless(boolean headless)` from `ChromeOptions` that has this code:

```
public ChromeOptions setHeadless(boolean headless) {
    args.remove("--headless");
    if (headless) {
        args.add("--headless");
        args.add("--disable-gpu");
    }
    return this;
}
```

But it didn't work either. I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199076/take-full-page-screen-shot-in-chrome-with-selenium) but since I already got how to retrieve some screenshots from 'headfull' browser I think this isn't my case either.

I'm using ChromeDriver from [this link(2.42)](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.42/)(the most recent at the time this question was made) and this dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: remove the headless option and try it again. Sometimes in headless browser screenshot is not taken.

Comment: @Hiten Sorry if I wasn't clear, I'll edit the question. I want some screenshots **with** headless mode on

Comment: Can you also add any exception your code returns?

Comment: In some website If we ran headless browser, then it will not work.
you can try with phantom js.

Comment: @BountyHunter All expcetions thrown were made by me and were part of my business logic, they have nothing to do with technical/infrastructure about Selenium or ChromeDriver

Comment: Can you update the question with the related code block where you get _blank images_?